# getting value from another table just for a cell for every row

Tags: mysql, sql

lets say I have tables

```
### Table 1 ###
id | id(foreign key from Table 2) | id(foreign key from Table 3)
------------
1    1    1
2    2    1

### Table 2 ###
id | title | id(foreign key from Table 3)
-----------------
1    Happy       1
2    Halloween   2

### Table 3 ###
id | name
1 | John
2 | Doe

### Expected Result ###
`Table 2`.`id` | `Table 2`.title | `Table 3`.name
-----------------------------------------------------
1                Happy                John
2                Halloween            Doe
```

I got the other two correct but I don't know how to get the names from table 3

SELECT `Table 2`.`id`, `Table 2`.`title`, `Table 2`. from `Table 2`, `Table 3` WHERE `Table 1`.`id` (foreign from table 2) = `Table 2`.`id`

because currently it's only showing John

```
### Current Result###
`Table 2`.`id` | `Table 2`.title | `Table 3`.name
-----------------------------------------------------
1                Happy                John
```

Comment: What results are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `Table 2`.`id2`, `Table 2`.`title`, `Table 3`.`name` 
    FROM `Table 2` 
    JOIN `Table 3` ON `Table 2`.`id3` = `Table 3`.`id3`
```

Where id2/id3 means your "Foreign key from Table 2/Table 3".